# Отображения сайта в браузерах

Tags: меню, joomla, браузер, cms, кроссбраузерность

Доброе время суток. Вопрос таков: почему в браузере Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, IE 6+ - Верхнее меню отображается нормально, а вот в Opera именно только верхнее меню сдвигается влево? CMS Joomla 2.5

Comment: сори) http://saratov-cson.ru/

Comment: Возможно опера некорректно отображает свойство float. Движок сайта здесь не при чём. Какая версия оперы?

Comment: В частности с 9 версии вплоть до 12.01 на всех такая байда...=( ранние версии не пробывал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте фиксированной ширину менюшки

```
#nav-left {
    float: left;
    width: 1055px;
}
```

И названия пунктов меню сделайте короче - они тупо не умещаются в один ряд.

Comment: Названия пунктов короче делать нельзя(( Спасибо